# Adding several different rasters to Geopackage containing project using PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, gdal, qgis-3, geopackage

I want to store different kinds of data in a project that would be stored on a geopackage. This will allow me to have all the information I'm interested in a single file.

I'm a Data Engineer and I want to eventually automate this which is why I'm using PyQGIS to do this. My code works well for several vector layers and for a single raster layer but everytime I try to add other rasters I get this error :

```
`GDAL ERROR 1: Unable to compute a transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates for geopackage/20231219_FG_AMG_01_03.gpkg. There is no affine transformation and no GCPs. Specify transformation option SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM to bypass this check.`
```

I have tried many iterations, using gdal.Warp and gdal.Translate to save the rasters to my geopackage. I have also tried reprojecting all of my rasters, even aligning them between each other and I still get the same results. Here's my current code for gdal :

```
ds = gdal.Open(raster_path)
gdal.Warp(
        geopackage_save_path,
        ds,
        format="GPKG",
        dstSRS="EPSG:4326",
        width=final_xsize,
        height=final_ysize,
        CreateOptions(["APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES", f"RASTER_TABLE={layer_name}"]
    )


resampled_layer = QgsRasterLayer(f"{geopackage_save_path}", layer_name)
    if resampled_layer.isValid():
        project.addMapLayer(resampled_layer, False)
        group.addLayer(resampled_layer)
```

I have also tried to use QgsRasterPipe :

```
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
provider = raster_layer.dataProvider()

layer_name = "test_layer"

file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(geopackage_save_path)
file_writer.setOutputFormat("gpkg")
file_writer.setCreateOptions(["APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES"])

# Save the raster to the GeoPackage
if pipe.set(provider.clone()):
    projector = QgsRasterProjector()
    projector.setCrs(provider.crs(), provider.crs())
    if pipe.insert(2, projector) is True:
        results = file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, final_xsize, final_ysize, provider.extent(), provider.crs())
```

I have also tried loading the rasters with `f"geopackage_save_path|layername={layer_name}"` but both options have the same results which is that I get a GDAL Error when loading the second raster.

The thing that really doesn't work is the `QgsRasterLayer(...)` part of the script. The rasters **do get saved on the geopackage** but I have been unable to load them as layers to put them in my project.

I have tried this code :

```
    layer = QgsRasterLayer(project_save_path,"test")
    raster_sub_layers = layer.dataProvider().subLayers()
    for sub_layer in raster_sub_layers:
        layer_name = sub_layer.split('!!::!!')[1]
        print(layer_name)
        test_layer = QgsRasterLayer(f"{project_save_path}", layer_name)
        if not test_layer.isValid():
            print(f"Main layer from '{project_save_path}' is not valid.")
```

(Also tried this code with different version of f"{project_save_path}|layername={layer_name}")
but I get a GDAL ERROR and my layers aren't loaded in the geopackage.

Comment: Sometimes it is good to learn the procedure by using gdal_translate or gdalwarp first. Have you tried to do that?

Comment: Do you mean using the CLI? Yes I’ve tried those options the problem in my opinion stems from my inability to save and then retrieve the raster from my geopackage. When I try to load more than 2 rasters from the geopackage and save it to my project (that’s also saved in my geopackage at the end of the script) I systematically get a GDAL error. 1 raster works fine. 
Maybe my project isn’t well initialized? I tried to force the CRS to WGS84 but it didn’t help